# Python Conda downgrading from Python 3.8.11 to Python 3.8.3

Tags: python, mysql, conda, mysql-connector

Will it affect downgrading python? I was trying to install a MySQL package. It came with this error

```
Specifications:

  - mysql-connector-python -> python[version='>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']

Your python: python=3.8
```

The other PC has 3.8.3 version python and it has MySQL installed.

Comment: How are you attempting to install it? Version 8.0.27 was released just over a month ago, and https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/ indicates support for Python 3.9. (I would suspect that support for 3.10, officially released shortly after the last version of `mysql-connnector-python`, is forthcoming.)

Comment: Which is to say, it looks like you are trying to install an old version of the package, and you should install the latest version rather than downgrading your Python.

Comment: @chepner how do I install latest version? `conda install -c anaconda mysql-connector-python` and I got above error

Comment: I don't know exactly how `conda` works, but it may have its own curated set of package versions that requires an upgrade of `conda` to upgrade the packages it will install.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `Pyenv` and install different version of `python`. `Pyenv` is a simple python versions manager and allows you to install multiple `python` versions and activate them whenever you need one.

So you can install a PC 3.8.3 and use the MySQL module

More informations [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). I hope this helps!